# Collapsible panel inside GridView

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I'm developing an ASP.NET 3.5 web application using C# with AjaxToolkKit. I have a following question.

How can I put a collapsible panel inside GridView to make a master and detail list that expands to display the detail panel when view link in a row is clicked? This is something similar to the download list in MSDN page.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Implement jQuery on the page. Have a look at the ajax methods, specifically in your case the load method. Show the master record on the page, along with a hidden div (you could inject it, but hey lets keep this simple ;). Bind the load to the click event of the master record displayed, and then use slideDown to show the hidden div on the page.

ie A very simply example of the load method, loading the html result from ajax/test.html into the element that is selected by 'result'

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html');
```